# Sql PHP date time

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I want to read all the user feed entered by the user in the last 2 days.
Table - user_feed
Column - date_n_time

What i'm looking for -
$result = "SELECT content FROM user_feed WHERE date_n_time >= (now() - 2 days)"

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Please explain your question in a clear way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually no need to use `DATE_SUB` - a simple subtraction works too. The only thing you were missing is the keyword `INTERVAL`, and that `day` must be singular.

```
SELECT content
FROM user_feed
WHERE date_n_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Answer (score 2):

Use date_sub:

[DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

So:

```
$result = "SELECT content FROM user_feed WHERE date_n_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) "
```